# Home cinema echo reduction

Tags: basement, audio

Bought a house and moved in, I decided to turn one of the basement rooms into a home cinema. Turns out the room has a lot of echo, way too much to enjoy a movie.

The walls are stone (plastered bricks), the floor is tiles, so all surfaces are hard. As it's a basement room, it only has two very small windows and one door. The room is fairly long (about 4m by 11m). So that is a lot of hard surface to echo from. And I don't have unlimited money left over.

What's a pragmatic way of reducing the echo in this room? Since it's a dedicated cinema room, I'm happy with putting panels on the walls and ceiling, or do whatever else wouldn't work for a living room - as long as it is reasonably cheap even given the size. That excludes most of the special noise-reduction panels that I've found online.

I've already hanged about 2m of curtains on the side walls near the screen, put some empty boxes around the room and some leftover carpet on the floor - to little effect. It probably covers too little of the total surface area.

Would putting styrofoam plates have an appreciable effect? Do I have to cover the ceiling? Is there something I can do with the placement of the speakers (5.1 system) ?

Comment: I would try to hang curtains or heavy cloth, canvas tarps , etc. to see if that fixes the problem. If it does then you can use that as research to find a more permanent solution.

Comment: If you search for DIY Perks on Youtube, there is a man that takes bath towels and turns them into sound absorbing panels. They actually turned out really nice and it only cost a few $$'s. These can be hung on the wall around the room and they absorb a lot of the rogue sounds.

Comment: Is the room empty right now?

The emptiness of a room is what allows sound waves to bounce around unimpeded from one surface (wall, ceiling, floor) to another, giving rise to that sharp, tinny echo.

Curtains won't help much as sound waves will just pass through them unless they're an inch thick or so. Boxes may help by reflecting sound in different directions (scattering).

Filling the room with furniture (esp. old wooden upholstered furniture), random junk, boxes stuffed with books and cushions etc. will create lots of irregular absorption and scattering and subdue the echo nicely.

Comment: Sure hope you "hung" rather than "hanged" curtains - dead cloth is bad :-)

Comment: Keeping speakers away from walls and especially away from corners will reduce the "boominess" .  In general, I would go with @bobs12 suggestions.

Comment: @Tom as others have said - the emptiness of a room will allow the sound waves to bounce. Carpet on the floor +1, Curtains +1, styro-foam or rubber coated surface on the walls will help, trying to use a curtain in front of the speakers might help dampen the effect . I am not sure if there is much you can do with out $pending $ome Ca$h.

Comment: Thanks so far. I'm ready to spend some cash, but due to the size of the room things like carpets will already run in the hundreds, curtains the same.

Does anyone have experience with cork? I can get some cork flooring cheaply and was wondering if it would absorb sound or not.

Furniture would be great, but again that's a big expense just for filling space. I tried a dozen or so empty boxes, to no effect.

Comment: @ScottRamboz - thanks a lot, there are indeed a lot of DIY accoustic panel videos on YouTube. I might have been thinking down the wrong road with curtains and carpets and whole-wall covering instead of panels.

Comment: Ummm... if you think spending "in the hundreds" is exhorbitant, you need a reality check.  Either this is going to end up as a highschooler's "mancave" or you will have to spend a realistic amount of cash.

Comment: @Tom Cork is a good idea, but I have sneaking suspicion that it may not affect the levels of sound in a room as compared to something with more known sound absorption(cloth / fabric from furniture or curtains). If you have access to it at a discount, I'd experiment with combining both sound absorbing materials with the cork. Even if it involves layering both together to create items you could hang or place around the room. I'm very interested in this topic now.

Comment: @ScottRamboz I was specifically thinking about cork flooring, which would run me something like $100 instead of the $2000 they quoted me for a wall-to-wall carpet. Will probably go and check it out, I have a suspicion that as a flooring the cork will not be porose.